# (Neko) "alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed" instead of error message

Tags: exception, runtime-error, haxe, neko

I'm making a game using Haxe and targeting neko. Any uncaught exception leads to alc_cleanup error.

The problem is, this error blocks the output of the exception details.

It's annoying because I use assertions so I can't find out which one threw an exception if one of the tests fail.

Any help here?

Comment: What frameworks are you using?

Comment: Just remember that any crash for any reason will call this error. I've learned that it just means something is null where it shouldn't be, and the raised exception crashed the sound system for no related reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alc_cleanup` error simply happens because an OpenAl audio device in use (by your game or an underlying framework) hasn't been closed before terminating the program (due to the uncaught exception).

If you can, you might want to catch and log that exception yourself to prevent it from being corrupted by the `alc_cleanup` error:

```
static function main()
{
    try {
       // do stuff
    } catch (e:Dynamic) {
        trace('ERROR: $e');
        trace(haxe.CallStack.toString(haxe.CallStack.exceptionStack()));
        Sys.exit(1);
    }
}
```

You could also:

- try to find the proper API in the frameworks you use to destroy the OpenAl context
- `neko.Lib.rethrow` the exception after doing the necessary cleanup yourself